# How do I know that I have deleted everything I did in Git?

Tags: git

I want to delete everything I did in git. I use the command `git reset HEAD`to delete all the progress but I don't know if delete all the progress.

Comment: `git reset HEAD` only resets the index, not the working tree. If you want to discard all changes, you need to reset `--hard`.

Comment: *typo*. I used the git command 'git reset --hard'.

Comment: And why don't you know whether or not that worked? Have you checked the `git status`?

Comment: Yes, but the HEAD with the name that I put in it still comes out. Sorry, if I can't explain myself, I've only been learning for days.

Comment: Could you include the output of `git status` in the question? It's unclear what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the commits up until a specific commit, first run `git log` into the command line to find the specific commit id and then run `git reset --hard <commit-id>`

To remove the last commit from git, you can simply run `git reset --hard HEAD^` If you are removing multiple commits from the top, you can run `git reset --hard HEAD~2` to remove the last two commits.

Answer (score 0):

- Unstage a staged file:

```
git reset HEAD name-of-file
```

- Unmodify a modified file (dangerous command, overwrites all modifications):

```
git checkout -- name-of-file
```

- Delete remote branch:

```
git push name-of-server --delete name-of-branch-to-delete
```

See also https://github.com/George-Creekbed/summary-of-git-commands/blob/main/git_commands.pdf .